# Elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ acting as an identity on $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$, for $G$ a nonabelian, simple group

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $f$ be an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut} G)$ s.t $f(r)$ is equal to $r$ for all $r \in \operatorname{Inn}(G)$. Prove that $f(j)$ is equal to $j$,  $\forall f\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ where G is non-abelian and simple.

I have taken an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, say $h$ then $h$ is equal to $g\cdot k$ where $g\in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and $k\in \operatorname{Inn}(G)$. Next what?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895376/elements-of-operatornameaut-operatornameautg-acting-as-an-identity-on

Answer (score 6):

Let $I ={\rm Inn}(G) \cong G$, $A = {\rm Aut}(G)$ and $B = {\rm Aut}(A)$. Since $Z(A)=1$, we have $A \cong {\rm Inn}(A)$, so we can identify $A$ with the normal subgroup ${\rm Inn}(A)$ of $B$.

Now $C:=C_B(I)$ is also a normal subgroup of $B$ and so $[C,A] \le C \cap A = 1$, because no nontrivial element of $A$ centralizes $I \cong G$. So $C$ centralizes $A$ i.e. $C$ acts as the identity on ${\rm Aut}(G)$.

Comment: Derek Holt Actually we have to prove C is B. I have 1 question that C is in B & A is Aut(G) what does (C,A) means & how is it subgroup of B?

Comment: Again write a clear definition of C. Derek Holt

Comment: Derek Holt will you please mention what C is? Because I is in AutG but B is Aut(AutG)

Comment: I have defined $C$. It is the centralizer in $B$ of $I$, which is the same as the subgroup of $B$ that acts as the identity on $I$. I am regarding $A$ as a subgroup of $B$, which makes life easier. You wanted to prove that $C$ acts as the identity on $A$, which is what I have done. In fact this proves that $C=1$.

Comment: For any group $G$ with $Z(G)=1$, you use the isomorphism $G \cong {\rm Inn}(G)$ to think of $G$ as a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$. Perhaps this is what is confusing you, but it makes calculations in ${\rm Aut}(G)$ easier, because the subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ that acts trivially on some subgroup of $G$ is then the same thing as the centralizer of that subgroup.

Comment: No that was not confusion actually. Ok I've got your point. But why the centralizer of I in B acts as an identity on I? lly why centralizer of A in B acts as an identity on A?

Comment: Look again at my answer to your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889399 $N$ centralizing ${\rm Inn}(G)$ is equivalent to $N$ acting trivially on $G$. It is exactly the same situation here: $B$ centralizes $I$ means $B$ acts as identity on $I$. Think about it!

Comment: @Derec Holt i) if $N$ centralizes $I\Rightarrow N$ acting trivially on $G$ then $B$ centralizes $I\Rightarrow B$ acting trivially on $G$.. isn't it?? Again can you please explain more  sir??